# Excel: if match cell of two table, write yes

Tags: excel, match

I have two table.

The first table is:
[image]

The second table is:
[image]

If 'SpotID' of second table matches with 'spot'of first table, I would like to return Yes.

I'm trying several methods, but they don't work.
I also splitted the SpotID in two values (batch and N°Spot) and tried MATCh with multiple critiria, but doesnt work. It seems that the string for example B10-212 (second table) doesn't find match with B10-212 (first table). If I make match with number, it works.

Couls you help me?

Comment: "*I've tried several methods*" can you show those formulas you've tried to ensure there wasn't an error in those?

Comment: Additionally, would you please elaborate further on how you want to match, as well as the final output?  The more detail the better (which the above requested formulas might help to explain).  Please ensure all data is posted WITHIN your question by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58505917/edit).

Comment: You can use **[COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)** to count if the value appears, combined with an IF. If COUNTIF = 0, then NO, else YES

Answer (score 1):

If the first Sheet is Sheet1 and the second Sheet2, you could write the following formula on Cell D2 of Sheet2, and then fill it down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!D:D,0)),"No","Yes")
```

If the value from A2 is found in Sheet1 Column D, then write Yes, else write No.

Comment: This formula should work, but I think there is a problem since the match I need refers to char (e.g. B10-212). I have the two table in the same sheet, do you think I have to put in separate sheets?Is it this a problem?

Comment: @Giovanna It shouldn't matter if it is in the same or different Sheets, all you would have to do is amend the ranges in the Match formula, I've tested this by using B10-212, which matched with no issues, can you make sure that they are both formatted in the same way and it should work....

Comment: It doesn't work. I solved by extracting only number from spotID. In this way by using index/match I get what I was founding. Thank you for your help